# Adding eventListener to blur event on custom component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a component called `styled-input` and it's an input with styles, icons, validation, etc.

I am trying to use `addEventListener` inside a custom directive to listen to events and make things happen.

```
<styled-input
    v-model=""
    v-on:input=""
    v-on:blur=""
></styled-input>
```

Internally:
`value` is a prop (allowing for `v-model` binding outside)

```
<template>
    <div>
        <input 
            v-bind:value="value"
            v-on:input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)"
            v-on:blur="$emit('blur', $event.target.value)"
        />
    </div>
</template>
```

I'm trying to `addEventListener`s to the tag through custom directives for custom validation.

```
<styled-input
    v-model=""
    v-custom-validator:credit-card
></styled-input>
```

Inside the directive I am using `addEventListener` to listen to events from the input field.

```
Vue.directive('custom-validator', {
    bind: function(el, binding) {
        el.addEventListener('blur', (event) => {
            // Does not fire
        });

        el.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
            /// Fires
        });
    },
});
```

Why doesn't the blur event fire, while the input event fires?

How can I get the blur event to fire?

Comment: Why do you want to force another element's event? Wouldn't that be cleaner to just call the action associated to it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Why blur fails

You are not picking the `blur` because you are not specifying the [**`useCapture` argument**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). It is mandatory because [**`blur` event does not bubble**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/blur). So adding the `useCapture` would fix your problem:

```js
el.addEventListener('blur', (e) => {
  // it will work now
}, true); // useCapture is the third argument to addEventListener
```

## Don't confuse Native DOM events with Vue events

From the your code (and see demo below), it may *seem* that when `blur` and `input` are triggered, the `.addEventListener()` picks what was emitted by `$emit()`. **That is not the case**.

You may get that idea because, besides those `$emit()`s at your `v-on`s, the `<input>` will **also** trigger the native events `blur` and `input`.

So what you actually have is two different kinds of events for `blur` and two for `input` (see demo below).

## What is up with `$emit()`?

`$emit()` is internal to Vue. It is a part or [**every Vue**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-on-with-Custom-Events) instance [**events interface**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Instance-Methods-Events).

`.addEventListener()` is for native DOM events. It will listen to [`.dispatchEvent()`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent), not `$emit()`s.

To listen to Vue's `$emit()`s you must use Vue's `.$on()`.

See demo below. Notice the `e` (event) object from the `.$on()` and from the `.addEventListener()` are **different**.

```js
Vue.component('my-comp', {
  template: '#styled-input-tpl',
  props: ['value']
});

Vue.directive('my-directive', {
  bind: function (el, binding, vnode) {
    vnode.componentInstance.$on('blur', function (e) {
      console.log('received $on(blur) - event value:', event);
    });
    vnode.componentInstance.$on('input', function (e) {
      console.log('received $on(input) - event value:', e);
    });
    
    el.addEventListener('blur', (e) => {
      console.log('received NATIVE(blur) - event value:', e.target);
    }, true);  // <======================================================= IMPORTANT
    
    el.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
        console.log('received NATIVE(input) - event value:', e.target);
    });
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<template id="styled-input-tpl">
    <div>
        <input 
            v-bind:value="value"
            v-on:input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)"
            v-on:blur="$emit('blur', $event.target.value)"
        />
    </div>
</template>

<div id="app">
  Edit the input, focus out, and check the console.
  <my-comp v-my-directive :value="'edit me'"></my-comp>
</div>
```

Comment: Just a follow up question to this. How do I access the current value of the component's `v-model` from inside the directive?

Comment: It depends. Inside the component, you can't tell if the parent used `v-model` or simply `:value` (because `v-model` is just a shorthand/syntactic sugar for `:value`+`@input`). Anyway, what I think you want is `vnode.componentInstance.$props`, is it?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I wanted. Thanks man. Last question, with `vnode.componentInstance.$on` do you need to manually remove the listener? (just like you do with `removeEventListener`

Comment: You may need to. There are other different methods in the API that may handle your use case: `$once()` and `$off()`. See docs: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Instance-Methods-Events

Comment: `vnode.componentInstance` is not defined in directive :)