# How to pass @blur into child component Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, blur, vee-validate

I created a custom Input component.

I needed pass @blur from *vee-validate* form to my custom input component.

It works great in normal html input tag. I no idea how could we pass the @blur into custom Input component.

Example 1 work correctly, it triggered the validation after blur the input.

```
 <template>
  <form @submit="onSubmit">
    <input @blur="emailBlur" v-model="email" type="text" autocomplete="off" name="email" placeholder="email">
    <button type="submit" :disabled="isSubmitting">Submit</button>
  </form>
 </template>
```

Example 2 with My custom Input Component:

```
// src/components/Input.vue
<template>
  <div class="mt-2">
    <label :for="name" class="h5">Name</label>
    <input
      :type="type"
      :value="modelValue"
      @change="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)"
      :id="name"
      :placeholder="placeholder"
      />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Input',
  props: ["modelValue", 'name', 'type', 'placeholder'],
  setup(props) {
    console.log('props :>> ', props); // not receive the @blur 
  }
}
</script>
```

Parent Component (App.vue):

```
<template>
  <form>
   <Input @blur="emailBlur" v-model="email" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Custom input email" />
    <button type="submit" :disabled="isSubmitting">Submit</button>
  </form>

</template>

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Input
  },
  setup() {
     // the vee validation values v-model to template
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this "[Adding eventListener to blur event on custom component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49311741/adding-eventlistener-to-blur-event-on-custom-component)" answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sending the handler as props from the parent is not a good practice instead need to trigger the handler(present in the parent) from the child component. By doing so you will have an advantage where you can bind different blur handlers based on your requirement inside different parent components

To do so you can follow the below approach

**Custom Input Component**

```
// src/components/Input.vue
<template>
  <div class="mt-2">
    <label :for="name" class="h5">Name</label>
    <input
      :type="type"
      :value="modelValue"
      @change="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)"
      :id="name"
      :placeholder="placeholder"
      @blur="$emit('blur')" //Change added
      />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Input',
  props: ["modelValue", 'name', 'type', 'placeholder'],
  emits: ['blur', 'update:modelValue'], // change added
}
</script>
```

**Note:**

for all v-models without arguments, make sure to change props and events name to modelValue and update:modelValue respectively

For Example:

Parent.vue

```
<ChildComponent v-model="pageTitle" />
```

and in Child.vue it should be like

```
export default {
  props: {
    modelValue: String // previously was `value: String`
  },
  emits: ['update:modelValue'],
  methods: {
    changePageTitle(title) {
      this.$emit('update:modelValue', title) // previously was `this.$emit('input', title)`
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for solve my issue. And make me understanding how the vue logics.

Comment: In my case, Vue warn me to add "update:modelValue" into emits array. Could i know why we need it?

Comment: yes you need to add it, I have added the reason as a note in the answer itself. Pls check

Comment: Forwarding the `blur` event up is technically working but it is not the correct way how to design `input` wrapper as you are forced to add new event handler (and into 'emits') for every possible event and new prop for every possible native `input` attribute (for example `readonly` or `maxlength`). Using `inheritAttrs` is the way to reduce the code needed and will make your life easier ...

Comment: @MichalLevý Since he asked for blur and change I have given that example. But. If you ask me I ll go with v-model itself

Comment: Yeah, you gave a bad example

Answer (score 0):

What you are creating is usually called "transparent wrapper" component. What you want from this wrapper is to behave in almost every way as normal `input` component so the users of the component can work with it **as it was** normal `input` (but it is not)

In your case, you want to attach `@blur` event listener to your wrapper. But the problem is that `blur` is native browser event i.e. not a Vue event.

When you place event listener on a component for an event not specified in [emits option](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/options-data.html#emits) (or `v-bind` an attribute that is not specified in component's `props`), Vue will treat it as [Non-Prop Attribute](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-attrs.html#non-prop-attributes). This means it take all such event listeners and non-prop attributes and place it on the **root node** of the component (`div` in your case)

But luckily there is a way to tell Vue "Hey, don't place those automatically on root, I know where to put it"

1. Use `inheritAttrs: false` [option](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-attrs.html#disabling-attribute-inheritance) on your component
2. Put all non-prop attributes (including the event listeners) on the element you want - `input` in this case - using `v-bind="$attrs"`

Now you can even remove some props - for example `placeholder` (if you want), because if you use it directly on your component, Vue place it on `input`, which is what you want...

**Also** handling `@change` event is not optimal  - you component allows to specify a `type` and [different input types has different events](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/forms.html#basic-usage). Nice trick around it is not to pass `value` and bind event explicitly, but instead use `v-model` with `computed` (see example below)

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      text: ""
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onBlur() {
      console.log("Blur!")
    }
  }
  
})

app.component('custom-input', {
  inheritAttrs: false,
  props: ["modelValue", 'name', 'type'],
  emits: ['update:modelValue'],
  computed: {
    model: {
      get() { return this.modelValue },
      set(newValue) { this.$emit('update:modelValue', newValue) } 
    }
  },
  template: `
  <div class="mt-2">
    <label :for="name" class="h5">{{ name }}:</label>
    <input
      :type="type"
      v-model="model"
      :id="name"
      v-bind="$attrs"
    />
  </div>
  `
})

app.mount("#app")
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.19/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
<div id='app'>
  <custom-input type="text" name="email" v-model="text" placeholder="Type something..." @blur="onBlur"></custom-input>
  <pre>{{ text }}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Cool. Your comment helps me better understanding the under hood what vue did.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. It makes me to know more about vue.